# android sorting array

Tags: java, sorting

I am having some issues sorting an array, I wish to sort the array by day which can be either Monday,Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday or Friday. I have a class which displays everything within the array but I want to order this by the days above, how can I do this?

I've tried using collections.sort and Arrays.sort but doesn't seem to give me the desired effect, any ideas?

```
public void sortArray() {



}
```

04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.assignment.timetable/org.assignment.timetable.Timetable}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at org.assignment.timetable.Timetable$MyComparator.compare(Timetable.java:51)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at org.assignment.timetable.Timetable$MyComparator.compare(Timetable.java:1)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:320)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:185)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:169)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1907)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1972)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at org.assignment.timetable.Timetable.sortModules(Timetable.java:71)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at org.assignment.timetable.Timetable.onCreate(Timetable.java:40)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-23 12:55:49.010: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  ... 11 more

Comment: use Arrays.sort() on your array, and create your own comparator.

Comment: is their any tutorials on this?

Comment: Google is your friend, here is one example of creating a comparator:
http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/
I'll throw together a quick example too.

Comment: Here's another http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: These both are sorting items when they are added i want to take the array already held and sort by day then display the new output

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
    //Assuming that the Module-class has the day stored as a String named "day"
static class MyComparator implements Comparator<Module>{
    private final static HashMap<String, Integer> order = getMap();

    @Override
    public int compare(Module lhs, Module rhs){
        int leftOrder = order.get(lhs.day.toLowerCase());
        int rightOrder = order.get(rhs.day.toLowerCase());
        return leftOrder - rightOrder;
    }

    private final static HashMap<String, Integer> getMap(){
        HashMap<String, Integer> res = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        res.put("monday",0);
        res.put("tuesday",1);
        res.put("wednesday",2);
        res.put("thursday",3);
        res.put("friday",4);

        return res;
    }
}
```

And when you have created your array (any way you want) you can sort it like so:

```
Arrays.sort(myArray, new MyComparator());
```

Or if you have a list:

```
Collections.sort(myList, new MyComparator());
```

The items in your array will now be sorted.

Comment: I made it like an inner class, but technically it could be defined anywhere.

Comment: getting this error and I had to remove the Override within MyComparator: The method sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Module>, Timetable.MyComparator)

Comment: @mitchnufc First of all, the `Arrays.sort()` is for arrays, not lists, for a list (such as ArrayList) you would use `Collections.sort()` instead.  
Secondly, You didn't mention that you had a custom class for the days, so I assumed they where strings. Just get the type from your `Module` class and use that instead of the strings in the map, and replace `<String>` with `<Module>`

Comment: sorry for the confussion, so do I just stick the Module and replace the String in the HashMap only?

Comment: @mitchnufc I edited the example a bit. it's a little bit hard to make it good as I don't know how you store the day in your Module-class.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that, could i run another method that sorts them my time as well after they've been sorted my day?

Comment: Yeah, but then the sorting-by-day would be undone. Instead expand on the day-comparator to sort by time if the days are equal.

Comment: The code doesn't work as it causes the app to crash when trying to sort

Comment: @mitchnufc `NullPointerException` in compare - either one of the Modules don't have a day, or it is not spelled the same as in the map.

Comment: just check and mine are spelt exactly the same as in this has map and yet the same problem persists

Comment: @mitchnufc well, something is clearly null, either one of the Modules in your array, one of their day-values or they can't be found in the map. Put some logging in there to see which one, and fix it. The comparator in it self does work, I have tested it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public WeekComparator implements Comparator {
private String[] weeksdays = {"monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"};
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
  if(!(o1 instanceof String && o2 instanceof String)) {
    throw new ClassCastException();
  }
  int day1 = indexOfDay((String)o1);
  int day2 = indexOfDay((String)o2);
  if(day1==day2) return 0;
  return (day1>day2 ? 1 : -1);
}

private int indexOfDay(String s) {
  for(int i = 0 ; i < weekdays.length;i++) {
    if(weekdays[i].equalsIgnoreCase(s)) return i;
  return 10;
}
```

}

I haven't tested this, but should work.. on paper (eh...screen)